# Mathematica not solving this integral

Tags: mathematica-online

I am trying to solve for
[image: integral]

But it is returning the same. I need this to complete my research.
Please help.

The expression used by me in mathematica is:

```
Integrate[Log2[1+x^2]*(PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x]),{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

Comment: If it is returning the same, then Mathematica does not want to compute it. Try doing it numerically. Also, if there's a next time, can you, please, consider posting your question appropriately? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load Mathematica code (not an image) so that respondents can copy the same to their notebooks and experiment with it. How do you know that a closed-form solution exists for this integral?

Comment: While I have upvoted the answer by @BobHanlon as I find it useful, I am befuddled -to say the least- by the upvote in the question. Would the person who upvoted care to elaborate on the rationale?

Comment: The basic problem that I have to solve is: Find the expected value of                         log2(1+b*(x^2)) where x is a non-standard normal random variable and b is a constant

Comment: If `b` is close to zero we get: `b Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma] (\[Mu]^2 + \[Sigma]^2)`. See: `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 E^(-((x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) Log[1 + b x^2], {x, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {b, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is obvious to consider a numerical solution

```
int[\[Mu]_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[E^(-((x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) Log[1 + x^2]/(2 Pi \[Sigma] Log[2]), {x, -Infinity, \[Mu] - \[Sigma], \[Mu], \[Mu] + \[Sigma], Infinity} ] 

Show[Table[ LogLogPlot[int[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {\[Sigma], .05, 10} ], {\[Mu], Range[0, 2, .1]}] ]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Thanks to@yarchik's comment!

Knowing `DiracDelta[x-\[Mu]]=Limit[E^(-((x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)))/(Sqrt[2Pi]\[Sigma]),\[Sigma]->0]` it follows

```
`int[\[Mu],0]==Log[1+\[Mu]^2]/(Sqrt[2Pi] Log[2])`
```

Comment: I have a bit of doubts that your results at $\sigma\rightarrow0$ are accurate. Your graph shows that for $\mu=2$ and $\sigma=0$ the value is $\approx 3$, but it should be $\log(1+\mu^2)/\log(2)=\log(5)/\log(2)=2.3$. Notice that integral is trivial for $\sigma=0$.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks for the hint , see my modified answer

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0;

(int = Inactive[Integrate][
  Log2[1 + x^2] PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x],
  {x, -∞, ∞}])//TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The integral does not evaluate; however, when `μ == 0`

```
int0 = int /. μ -> 0 // Activate

(* -(1/(σ^2 Log[
   2]))(HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, 1/(
    2 σ^2)] + σ^2 (EulerGamma - π Erfi[1/(
        Sqrt[2] σ)] + Log[2] - 2 Log[σ])) *)

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200},
  LogLogPlot[int0, {σ, 10^-4, 10},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   MaxRecursion -> 5,
   WorkingPrecision -> 120,
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
      {HoldForm@σ, HoldForm@int0})]] //
 Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: The condition over μ and σ is very stringent, and we cannot consider it 0. Is there any other approximation that can be used? Thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 1):

*For the benefit of cut-and-pasters, there is an alternate form at the bottom.*

$\text{expr}=\text{FullSimplify}[\text{PDF}[\text{NormalDistribution}[0,\sigma ],x]]$

$\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }$

$\text{Assuming}\left[\sigma \in \mathbb{R}\land \sigma >0,\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \text{expr} \log \left(x^2+1\right) \, dx\right]$

$-\frac{\, _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{1}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)}{\sigma ^2}+\pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+2 \log (\sigma )-\gamma -\log (2)$

The purpose of expr is to completely remove $\mu$ whixh is known to be 0 in this case.

The purpose of the Assuming first expresson is to inform Mathematica that $\sigma$ is positive real.

Perhaps, I missed something?

For the cut-and-pasters (afterwards, right click on the cell bracket and Convert to Standard Form):

```
expr = FullSimplify[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], x]]

1/(E^(x^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*\[Sigma]))

Assuming[Element[\[Sigma], Reals] && \[Sigma] > 0,
  Integrate[expr*Log[x^2 + 1], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

-EulerGamma + Pi*Erfi[1/(Sqrt[2]*\[Sigma])] - 
  HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, 1/(2*\[Sigma]^2)]/
  \[Sigma]^2 - Log[2] + 2*Log[\[Sigma]]
```

---

This also works:

$\text{Assuming}\left[\mu =0,\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \log \left(x^2+1\right) \text{PDF}[\text{NormalDistribution}[\mu ,\sigma ],x] \, dx\right]$

```
Assuming[\[Mu] == 0, Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x]*  
Log[x^2 + 1], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely someone will check your answer or perhaps help if there's an issue. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I edited my answer to display both TraditionalForm and RawInputForm expressions.  I opine that the former is readable and the latter is copy-and-pastable. Both groups get what they want.